# ZeroMQ Windows Installer NSIS Error

Tags: windows, nsis, zeromq

I want to install ZeroMQ for Ratchet/PHP and I downloaded the installer from http://zeromq.org/distro:microsoft-windows. But I keep getting "NSIS error" whenever I try to install it.

[image: test]

It immediately shows after I run the installer. Different versions, x64 or x86 ones, none of them works. This problem only shows up with ZeroMQ installers.

Does anyone have any idea why does this happen?

P.S. I use Windows 8.1. (Up to date)

Answer (score 2):

This question does not belong here on Stackoverflow but since you posted it here anyway I will give you the technical answer: NSIS needs to open a file handle to itself so it can read the compressed data, it does this by calling `GetModuleFileName` to get the path and `CreateFile` to open the file. If this step fails it displays the `_LANG_CANTOPENSELF` message ("Error launching installer", the text in your screenshot).

**A)** `GetModuleFileName` can return a "incorrect" path when filesystem redirection is involved, this is most commonly seen when psexec is used to execute the program from the Windows directory on a remote 64-bit computer and this is probably not the case here?

**B)** The call to `CreateFile` can fail, this is most often caused by Anti-Virus software holding a lock/denying access to the file. Try to disable/uninstall any 3rd-party Anti-Virus software...

Comment: = Corrupted installer?